# How to download the latest dataset from Heroku hosted Express server

Tags: express, heroku

I have an express app hosted on Heroku with 2 end points that just point to 2 JSON files:

https://kingpongscores-server.herokuapp.com/players

https://kingpongscores-server.herokuapp.com/games

I have a version of this on Github (which is deploys from) and I want to update that repo so I can pull the latest data to my local, before making any changes.

The reason is at the moment if I add an end point/make a functionality change and push, I will override all the data on the Heroku server with the version I have locally.

Lastly, I realise I could just go to those end points and copy the data, but I'm going to have multiple versions of this server hosted at once, and going to be making lots of changes, so I don't want to do it manually.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+ephemeral+filesystem

Comment: Thanks @phd this revealed to me an issue I was having where the data kept getting reset (and now I know why, so cheers!)
Now I need to figure out how to get github to pull the data every 30 minutes to it stays up to date, then redeploy with that data.

Comment: I appreciate the link @phd, but none of these questions answer mine, they are all issues with getting it to deploy, I want it to PULL the data from Heroku.

Comment: Impossible, sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71300111/7976758 . Ephemeral filesystem doesn't persist. You should push your data to a persistent storage.