# How to update local branch with heroku remote

Tags: git, heroku, server

I'm pretty new in git so i'm learning commands... 
I created a remote repository for a project on Heroku. 
I'm facing a problem, when I push my updates on Heroku it overwrites some folders automatically created by my scripts that I need to keep. 
How can I update my local repository before pushing it on Heroku ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku cannot persist your folders created by your scripts. You must use object storage such as Google cloud platform or Amazon S3. Check [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775418/heroku-local-persistent-storage) as well.

Comment: isn't there any other way ? I mean isn't it possible to fetch all my files each time i want to push them ?

Comment: @XamMlr, no. Heroku dynos restart frequently and unpredictably. Changes to the local filesystem are lost every time that happens. This is a deliberate part of Heroku's architecture.